# Sum many columns that have a different counts rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Financial

```
             colum1      Project_Id
               100           1
               200           1
               550           2
               400           1
               700           1
               950           3
```

Table Technical

```
             colum1      Project_Id
              250            1  
              650            2
              200            1
```

Table Project

```
             Project_Id     project_Name   
              1                 Cairo
              2                 Giza
              3                 zagazig
```

We have 3 tables Project,Financial,Technical, Project tbl have a primary key Project_Id and both  Financial,Technical tables have a foreign key Project_Id

How can we create SQL select statement for this task to get the result?

```
Cairo      1400    450     950
Giza       550     650    -100
Zagazig    950      0      950
```

Comment: OK slow down. Let's see your full query and expected results. Please be clearer about what you are trying to do and what is going wrong

Comment: Aggregate *before* you join. (Cross?) Joining the above data will return 4 rows so the `SUM` of either column would be `1000` (`100 + 200 + 300 + 400 = 1000` and `250 * 4 = 1000`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sum all the values from financial and subtract sum of all the values from technical table without any relationship then use below query instead of join:

```
select (sum(colum1) -(select sum(column1) from technical))Result from Financial
```

Result should be **750**.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `left join` and aggregation.  For the data described in your question:

```
select f.project_id, sum(f.column1),
       coalesce(t.column1, 0), 
       sum(f.column1) - coalesce(t.column1, 0)
from financial f left join
     technical t
     on f.project_id = t.project_id
group by f.project_id, t.column1;
```

Note:  If `technical` can have multiple rows per project, the above will not work -- but the data in your question has at most one row per project in `technical`. However, it is fairly simple to modify.

If technical can have multiple rows, then pre-aggregate:

```
select f.project_id, f.x,
       coalesce(t.x, 0), 
       sum(f.x) - coalesce(t.x, 0)
from (select f.project_id, sum(f.column1) as x
      from financial f
      group by f.project_id
     ) f left join
     (select t.project_id, sum(t.column1) as x
      from technical t
      group by t.project_id
     ) t
     on f.project_id = t.project_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, We got close to the goal.

Comment: yes, technical can have multiple rows per project.

Comment: Column 'f.Project_Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: to solve this problem we need to add 
group by f.Project_Id, f.x,t.x;

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, your answer is right, exactly when we add group by in the end of query

```
     select f.project_id, f.x,
       coalesce(t.x, 0), 
       sum(f.x) - coalesce(t.x, 0)
from (select f.project_id, sum(f.column1) as x
      from financial f
      group by f.project_id
     ) f left join
     (select t.project_id, sum(t.column1) as x
      from technical t
      group by t.project_id
     ) t
     on f.project_id = t.project_id
     group by f.Project_Id, f.x,t.x;
```